# get friends after a specific id using facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook

I am using facebook graph api to get details of my friends . I wanted to get details of my friends after a specific user id for eg i have 4 friends

```
uid     name

1       Rob

2       Ryan

3       Bob

4       Angelina
```

Now i want to get details of my friends after user id 2 means of user id 3 and 4 and so on .

I used the following graph search query

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user.'/friends?uid>=2';
```

But it does not seems to be working . I searched a lot for this but no information . There is a option for limit but no option to perform what i want. Any help on this ? Below is my full code

```
 function getFacebookFriends_more($criteria='') {
$name = $criteria['name'];
$load_me_more_id = $criteria['load_more_id'];

if($name=='') $name = 'me';

$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$name.'/friends?uid>='.$load_me_more_id.'fields=gender,name&access_token='.$this->getAccessToken();
$content = $this->getDataFromUrl($url);
$content = json_decode($content,true);

$users = $this->formatFacebookUsers_more($content,$load_me_more_id);

return $users;
  }

     function formatFacebookUsers_more($content,$load_me_more_id) {


   for($i=0; $i<count($content['data']); $i++) {

    $id = $content['data'][$i]['id'];
    $name = $content['data'][$i]['name'];
    $gender = $content['data'][$i]['gender'];
    $url = 'http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id='.$id;
    $picture = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id.'/picture?type=large'; //square, small, large


    $users[$i]['id'] = $id;
    $users[$i]['name'] = $name;
    $users[$i]['picture'] = $picture;
    $users[$i]['url'] = $url;
    $users[$i]['gender'] = $gender;

}
return $users;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as the person wont have every user in facebook as his friend.

**(ie) a person may have *user3* in his friend list but not *user4* but have *user5***

You need to store all the friends UID in an array and then iterate over it.

Assuming you have an authorized session

```
 $friends = $facebook->api("/me/friends");
```

Now iterate over friends array

Comment: let me paste my full code i stored it but it does not seems to be working still

Comment: i pasted the full code could you please have a look and guide me

Comment: You cannot use '>=' in

`$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$name.'/friends?uid>='.$load_me_more_id.'fields=gender,name&access_token='.$this->getAccessToken();`


You can only get information about a particular UID at a time.

Comment: even if this query runs it gives all friends . and even if dont use `uid>='.$load_me_more_id.'` which would be correct then i get all friends i pasted code to show that i am breaking down the values from json and is there a possible way that after that i can separate all the ids after a specific friend id i want?